# binding selected item angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I can not use `selectedItem1` in the controller for some calculation in the following code:

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
          <label>Vendere:</label> 
          <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>

   </div>
```

with the following controller:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []); 

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){


$scope.budget0=60;
    $scope.budget1=$scope.budget0 - $scope.selectedItem1.someprop;
}
```

I can understand why? Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to give initial value to `selectedItem1` Check out following example will help you:--

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {  
  $scope.rose = [{
    'nome': "abc",
    'costo':110
  }, {
    nome: "xyz",
    costo: 10
  }];

  $scope.selectedItem1 =  $scope.rose[0];// default selected item
  
  $scope.budget0 = 60;
  $scope.budget1 = $scope.budget0 - $scope.selectedItem1.costo;
  
  $scope.change = function(){
    $scope.budget1 = $scope.budget0 - $scope.selectedItem1.costo;
    console.log($scope.selectedItem1);  
    console.log($scope.budget0 +"-"+ $scope.selectedItem1.costo +"="+$scope.budget1);  
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-change="change()"
          ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>

  <br/>
  {{"budget1 == "+budget1}}
</div>
```

Comment: very helpful! thanks...i suppose the same if I have .rose from an '$http.get' service?